# $\int_1^\infty \operatorname{sech} x \cdot \ln x \ dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

The integral cant be expressed in "standard mathematical functions" -Wolfram
I'm asked to determine if its convergent or divergent (I can do that via comparison theorem) and its convergent (and wolfram agrees) but them I'm asked to evaluate because it's convergent. Am I missing something? Is there a way to evaluate if I cant express the integral?

Comment: As for "evaluating" it, the definite integral (approximately $0.43049780563463779025$ probably can't be expressed in closed form.
You could write it as a series: $2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} Ei(-2k-1)/(2k+1)$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{\color{red}0}^\infty\text{sech }x\cdot\ln x~dx ~=~ \frac\pi2\cdot\ln\frac{4~\pi^3}{\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac14\bigg)^4}$

Answer (score 1):

It is convergent for sure since:

$$ 0\leq \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{2\log x}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}\,dx\leq \int_{1}^{+\infty}2(x-1)e^{-x}\,dx = \frac{2}{e}.$$
The upper bound can be improved up to $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{e}$ if we exploit $\log x\leq\sqrt{x-1}$ for any $x\geq 1$.

Comment: Not sech of logx, its sechx multiplied by logx

Comment: Quote: "I'm asked to determine if its convergent or divergent (I can do that via comparison theorem) and its convergent".

Comment: @NawarIsmail What is used here is \begin{align} sech(x) = \frac{1}{\cosh(x)} = \frac{2}{e^{x} + e^{-x}} \end{align} and $\log(x) = \log_{e}(x) = \ln(x)$. What Jack has presented is demonstration that the integral is convergent and less than $2 \, e^{-1}$ in the event a closed form is obtained.

Comment: How did you obtain $2(x-1)e^-x$?

Comment: @Leucippus Nawar was responding to the previous version of this answer.

Comment: @NawarIsmail: $\log x\leq(x-1)$ for any $x\geq 1$ is equivalent to $\log(u+1)\leq u$ for anu $u\geq 0$ or to $e^{u}\geq 1+u$, pretty well-known. The other piece is just $e^{x}+e^{-x}\geq e^{x}$.

Comment: Thank you guys very much! Very helpful, but so is there no way to obtain an actual value?

Comment: @NawarIsmail: numerical integration returns $0.43049780563463779\ldots$. Interestingly, the integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$ equals 
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}\log\left(\frac{4\pi^3}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{4}}\right)$$ and the integral over $[0,1]$ can be computed from a Taylor expansion centered at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

One method to attempt to evaluate the integral is as follows.

Using 
\begin{align}
sech(x) = 2 \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \, e^{-(2k+1) \, x}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
I(x) &= \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1} \, dt}{\cosh(t)} \\
&= 2 \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \, \int_{1}^{\infty} t^{x-1} \, e^{-(2k+1) t} \, dt \\
&= 2 \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)^{x}} \, \int_{2k+1}^{\infty} e^{-u} \, u^{x-1} \, du \mbox{  where  } u = (2k+1) t \\
&= 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} \, \Gamma(x, 2k+1)}{(2k+1)^{x}},
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(x,\alpha)$ is one of the incomplete gamma functions. Now taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$ and setting $x=1$ leads to the desired integral being
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(t) \, dt}{\cosh(t)} = 2 \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} \, \Gamma'(1,2k+1)}{2k+1} - 2 \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} \, \ln(2k+1) \, \Gamma(1,2k+1)}{2k+1}.
\end{align}